# How to pass an Environment variable to openshft via Jenkisfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, openshift

I have this Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {
          maven 'maven381'
          jdk 'JDK904'
        oc 'oc'
    }
            parameters {
                string(name:'CLUSTER_NAME',defaultValue:'openshift-cluster',description:'Cluster name space')
                string(name:'PROJECT_NAME',defaultValue:'etias-sword-dev',description:'Cluster project name')
            }

  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        script {
          openshift.withCluster(CLUSTER_NAME) {
           openshift.withProject(PROJECT_NAME) {
            openshift.newApp('--image-stream="openshift/java:11"~https://github.com/filip123go/Simplest-Spring-Boot-Hello-World.git --env=MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2')

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to pass inside the Environment variable

> MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

so every time I run the job in Jenkins the Environment variable passes automatically.
I know that the cli command in openshift is

> oc set env bc simplest-spring-boot-hello-world
> MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2

I have already tried with no success

> openshift.newApp('--image-stream="openshift/java:11"~https://github.com/filip123go/Simplest-Spring-Boot-Hello-World.git --env=MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2')

and

> openshift.newApp('--image-stream="openshift/java:11"~https://github.com/filip123go/Simplest-Spring-Boot-Hello-World.git
> --param=MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2')

and

> openshift.newApp('--image-stream="openshift/java:11"~https://github.com/filip123go/Simplest-Spring-Boot-Hello-World.git
> MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2')

and

> openshift.newApp('--image-stream="openshift/java:11"~https://github.com/filip123go/Simplest-Spring-Boot-Hello-World.git
> -e=MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2')

with no success.
Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation (and by reading the documentation) this is the correct way  to pass inside the Environment variable

> openshift.newApp('--image-stream="openshift/java:11"~https://github.com/filip123go/Simplest-Spring-Boot-Hello-World.git --build-env  MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2')

this is the updated Jenkins File :

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  tools {
          maven 'maven381'
          jdk 'JDK904'
        oc 'oc'
    }
            parameters {
                string(name:'CLUSTER_NAME',defaultValue:'openshift-cluster',description:'Cluster name space')
                string(name:'PROJECT_NAME',defaultValue:'etias-sword-dev',description:'Cluster project name')
            }

  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        script {
          openshift.withCluster(CLUSTER_NAME) {
           openshift.withProject(PROJECT_NAME) {
            openshift.newApp('--image-stream="openshift/java:11"~https://github.com/filip123go/Simplest-Spring-Boot-Hello-World.git --build-env  MAVEN_OPTS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2')
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

}